# Has any one used Flex 1.5 for mobile apps?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flashlite

I know it's now Flash Builder 4 and it is great, but Flash Player for Mobile on Nokia is still quite not up to AS3.  My audience mostly has quite old Nokia phones that support FP 7-8.  Do any of you have experience with [Flex 1.5](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/15/) to create mobile apps?  Is my idea reasonable, or should I expect big problems if I go down this path?  I plan to use it to develop components like DataProviders for tables/lists and charts.

Comment: There is no Flex (1.5) for AS2. You are looking for Flash Lite. Note that you can't use the Flex framework for that.

Comment: There was. along time ago. (Dark or Light days of Macromedia) (Adobe does not support it as fas as I know but I have an old archive with it and with Flex Server it has a lot of docs on board, and knowing Flex 3 (mx component model) its easy to get into it)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

- [OpenLaszlo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openlaszlo/)
- [SVGT for Mobile(JSR-226)](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MobilityTutorialAboutSVG_beginners)
- [XULMidlet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlmidlet/)